# How to loop over JSON objects in a ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I want to loop over JSON objects and check for a condition in a ruby function.
I have 2 classes:

- Class `A`
- Class `B`

Class `A` has a function that reads the JSON file.
This function returns an array of hash objects representing the data:

```
def self.data
  path = 'data/songs.json'
  file = File.read(path)
  JSON.parse(file)
end
```

I want to use this method in class B to access the `songs.json` objects and check if a certain condition is `true`.

Here is the code for class B:

```
def mention_count 
  count = 0
  array= []
  array.push(Song.data)
  array.each do |i|
    if(@name === i[:name])
      count +=1;
    end
  end
end
```

Th JSON file has a key called `name`, and I am checking if it is identical to the class `B` variable name. If true the count variable is increased and returned.

The JSON file is an array of JSON object and it looks like this

```
[
{
"Name": "Bad",
"Artist": "Michael Jackson",
"Record": 825,
},
{
"Name": "Thriller",
"Artist": "Michael Jackson",
"Record": 846,
}]
```

I am not getting the expected result. The `array.push(Song.data)` is only adding the first object of the JSON file and not the whole JSON file.

How do I call the method `Song.data` in class `B` and loop over the JSON objects?

Comment: Could you please post (in your question) some of the sample JSON data you're reading from the file?

Comment: @SRack I have included  some JSON data

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has a lot of convenience methods that make this sort of thing really simple:

```
def mention_count
  Song.data.map do |song|
    song['Name']
  end.count(@name)
end
```

Here the `map` method is used to extract the song name, then `count` looks for how many instances of that particular name there are. You can also do it this way:

```
def mention_count
  Song.data.count do |song|
    @name == song['Name']
  end
end
```

Where that counts songs with matching names more directly.

Note that in your original code you're doing this:

```
array= []
array.push(Song.data)
```

This creates a new array, then adds the array to it *as an element*. If you wanted to add the elements of `Song.data` to the end of the array you'd have to do this:

```
array += Song.data
```

Which concatenates it. In any case this is irrelevant since you never modify `array` so you can just use `Song.data` directly.

Comment: I like `count do...` in there ^^ Very clean and readable. Know of any advantages to using either of your approaches or `reduce` as in my answer?

Comment: @SRack `reduce` and it's twin `inject` are very versatile, but not always as good as their special-purpose counterparts like `count`.

Comment: @tadman I am using the Song.data.count   method but the method returns 0 all the time even when there the count should increament. I'm I accessing the name key correctly or is there something else missing?

Comment: You'll want to check you're accessing the right property. What if it's `song.name` or `song['name']`? One quick way to find out is to call `Song.data.map { |s| s[:name }` on the console to see if you're getting the right output. Experiment as necessary.

Comment: Yep, I'd tend to agree tadman - `count do` slipped my mind when writing the answer. +1 for yours. @ShannonMakenna - I believe it'll be `song["Name"]` you need - when you parse the JSON it maintains the key structure; if you don't explicitly parse it, it'll be coerced into a hash with symbolised keys. Hope this gets you sorted :)

Comment: I've updated the code with keys taken from your JSON example. Remember Ruby is not only case sensitive, so `name` and `Name` are two different things as far as the computer is concerned, but it also won't auto-convert for you. `'1'` and `1` are not equivalent, nor is `:name` and `'name`'. One way to solve this problem is to do it incrementally, testing as you go using `irb`. Try `Song.data` and look at the results. Then `Song.data[0]` and `Song.data[0]['Name']` to experimentally navigate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems at first glance that you're wrapping an array of data (returned in class `A`) in another array in class `B`. Therefore, when you're calling `each` on the array, the first result is the original array. You get me?

Therefore, you could use:

```
Song.data.each do ....
  ...
end
```

Does that help?

Assuming that solves it, there's a purpose built method for this, where you can pass a count while you loop through your objects using [reduce(0)](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce).

I'd refactor the code in class `B` a little, as follows:

```
def mention_count 
  Song.data.reduce(0) do |count, i|
    count += 1 if @name == i[:name]
    count
  end
end
```

To briefly break this down:

- `reduce(0)` passes the arg (`0`) along with the objects you're looking to loop through (to `count` and `i` respectively)
- if `@name == i[:name]`, count is incremented
- `count` is returned, so it's available for the next item we loop through
- `reduce` then returns the value of count when all looping is complete

Hope that helps!

Comment: The `reduce` version here could be `count + (@name == i[:name] ? 1 : 0)` but that's kind of confusing.

Comment: I did consider that, but went with the above for readability's sake @tadman. I tend towards using `tap { ... }` on the accumulator when I know it's needed to be returned each timet, but it doesn't work with the integer specified here.

Comment: The `tap` method is really useful for getting out of a jam, but try not to over-use it. I see people spike it in places it doesn't belong just to save maybe one line of code and introduce a whole bunch of complexity and nuance anyway.